# How to create a User with 3 different roles and one place for sign up /sign in?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

The application consist of 3 type of user. Admin, Clients and Professionals.

**Clients**: signup with basic info(name, username, image, password, ...)

**Professionals**: signup with basic info above and much more (career, experiences, education, and much more....)

**Admin**: Whom control the whole app and it's users.

I created User model via Devise. Now I need to create these roles and one place for login (if it is possible).

Many articles advice not to create 3 models, because it would be a mess. How I would I achieve such solution?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You must use only one model (User) for all of this user types, in that model you can create one attribute (e.g. `role`) that will determine role of each user (e.g. 'admin', 'pro', 'simple') and then, based on `role`, you can use gem for authorization to decide what each type of user can do ([cancancan](https://github.com/CanCanCommunity/cancancan), [pundit](https://github.com/elabs/pundit)).
So all of your user will register and login the same way, but all will take different rights.

if you want to keep different additional info for this user types, you can create additional model for it (profile, account e.t.c.) and to offer users to fill it in depending on the type they chose on register step.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I got what you mean. I understand the first part where inside Ability.rb file I can defined 3 roles for Admin , Pro and Clients. Right?

About the second part, do you know of an example to share showing how to do it? Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

In such scenarios, best solution is using [`polymorphic associations`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#polymorphic-associations).

Let common attributes be in your `user` model, and other details in their corresponding models.

You can create a 2 step signup page, where let the user input common details first and in second step details based on the type of `user`.

Login can be single form.

You will find many tutorials and examples for it on the internet.